# How can I check the last character in a string in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line

I need to ensure that the last character in a string is a `/`

```
x="test.com/"

if [[ $x =~ //$/ ]] ; then
        x=$x"extention"
else
        x=$x"/extention"
fi
```

at the moment, false always fires.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ x="test.com/"
$ [[ "$x" == */ ]] && echo "yes"
yes

$ x="test.com"
$ [[ "$x" == */ ]] && echo "yes"
$ 

$ x="test.c/om"
$ [[ "$x" == */ ]] && echo "yes"
$ 

$ x="test.c/om/"
$ [[ "$x" == */ ]] && echo "yes"
yes

$ x="test.c//om/"
$ [[ "$x" == */ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

Comment: Awesome. What does the star denote? Will this get a false positive if x has multiple `/`?

Comment: @MildFuzz the asterisk `*` denotes "any character". So you can also do `[[ "$x" == *m/ ]] && echo "yes"` that will say yes in this case, but not in `x="test.comp/", for example. For multiple `/` it will be also fine, check my updated examples.

Answer (score 4):

You can index strings in Bash using `${var:index}` and `${#var}` to get the length of the string. Negative indices means the moving from the end to the start of the string so that `-1` is index of the last character:

```
if [[ "${x:${#x}-1}" == "/" ]]; then
    # last character of x is /
fi
```

Comment: Negative indices are allowed, but you need a space to distinguish substring expansion from default value expansion: `${x: -1}`. You aren't actually using a negative index, but a computed positive index.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition was *slightly* incorrect.  When using `=~`, the rhs is considered a pattern, so you'd say `pattern` and not `/pattern/`.

You'd have got expected results if you said

```
if [[ $x =~ /$ ]] ; then
```

instead of

```
if [[ $x =~ //$/ ]] ; then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this generically using bash substrings `$(string:offset:length}` - `length` is optional

`#x` is the length of x

Therefore

```
$n = 1       # 1 character
last_char = ${x:${#x} - $n}
```

For future references,

```
$ man bash
```

has all the magic

> ${parameter:offset:length}
>
> Substring Expansion.  Expands to up to length characters of parameter
>   starting at the character  specified  by offset.   If  length  is
>   omitted, expands to the substring of parameter starting at the
>   character specified by offset.  length and offset are arithmetic
>   expressions ...